# Does $3^u_02^v_0 + 3^u_12^v_1 ... = 3^s_02^t_0 + 3^s_12^t_1 + ...$ necessitate that $u=s$ and $v=t$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $s$, $t$, $u$, and $v$ be four sequences of natural integers of the same length $l$.
The sequences $s$ and $u$ are strictly decreasing, while $t$ and $v$ are strictly increasing.

Is it possible to have

$\sum_{i=1}^{l} 3^{u_i}2^{v_i} = \sum_{i=1}^{l} 3^{s_i}2^{t_i}$

without $(s,t)=(u,v)$ ?

If such solutions exist, is there a way to categorize them?

Comment: @Peter I am pretty sure my demo for $v_1=t_1$ is correct, and I wouldn't be surprised if it was easy to show that $u_l=s_l$ the same way, but I don't see clearly how you go from that to the whole sequences being equal.

Comment: I found a counterexample: u=[2,1], v=[0,3], s=[3,1], t=[0,1], that both give a result of 33

Comment: more generally: 3+8 = 9+2 = 11 (so u=[1,0], v=[0,3], s=[2,0], t=[0,1])
and for any k that can be written as a product of 3s and 2s: 3k+8k=9k+2k=11k